# Custom background for active window

Tags: emacs, text-editor

How can I configure a different background color for the active window in Emacs?

Comment: try `hiwin-mode` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24852800/1845302)

Answer (score 11):

Try Yoshida's hiwin-mode (visible active window mode): https://github.com/yoshida-mediba/hiwin-mode

Answer (score 10):

If by "window" you mean Emacs' definition of windows, i.e., panes, not really.

If by "window" you mean everyone else's conception of windows, which Emacs calls frames, then yes. Here's an example:

```lisp
(defadvice handle-switch-frame (around switch-frame-set-background)
  (set-background-color "white")
  ad-do-it
  (set-background-color "yellow"))
(ad-activate 'handle-switch-frame)

(defadvice delete-frame (after delete-frame-set-background)
  (set-background-color "yellow"))
(ad-activate 'delete-frame)
```

Comment: And if he wants it per-window, I would just recommend a reverse-video modeline.  If you need more of a visual cue than that, open fewer windows.

Comment: Uh, active modeline, that is.

Comment: I mean Emacs window. Highlight of mode line is not enough for me. I use large screen, lots of windows are open.. and quite often I've started to edit not the window I wanted to edit. I'll try if reverse-video mode will be some improvement

Comment: Well, there's always hacking the Emacs source.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative using the modeline inactive color matching the background so the only modeline with color is the active window.  I have a hooks for the minibuffer enter and exit, and also when switching windows. I use bold for certain modeline things like read only and the file name, so that the a different color doesn't stand out when switching windows.  When I enter the minibuffer, the active window modeline turns to inactive until I exit the minibuffer, or when I switch from an active minibuffer (leaving it open) to another window.  I had to set the modeline background box to match also.

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :background "black" :foreground "white"
  :font "Courier" :height 180)

(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
  :height 160 ;; affects everything
  :foreground "black" :background "gray70")

(set-face-attribute 'mode-line-inactive nil
  :foreground "gray70" :background "black" :box '(:line-width 1 :color "black"))

(defun enter-minibuffer-setup ()
  (whitespace-mode t)
  (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
    :height 160 :foreground "gray70" :background "black" :box '(:line-width 1 :color "black"))
  (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil :background "black" :foreground "cyan")
  (set (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
    '((default :background "black" :foreground "yellow"))) )

(defun exit-minibuffer-setup ()
  (cond
    ((or save-as-variable multi-extract-variable multi-attach-variable)
      (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil :height 160 :foreground "black" :background "#eab700"))
    (t (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil :height 160 :foreground "black" :background "gray70" :box nil)))
  (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil :background "black" :foreground "cyan"))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'enter-minibuffer-setup)

(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook 'exit-minibuffer-setup)

(defun lawlist-minibuffer-conditions ()
  (cond
    ((minibufferp)
      (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
        :height 160 :foreground "gray70" :background "black" :box '(:line-width 1 :color "black"))
      (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil :background "black" :foreground "cyan"))
    (t
      (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
        :height 160 :foreground "black" :background "gray70")
      (set-face-attribute 'minibuffer-prompt nil :background "black" :foreground "gray70")) ))

(defun lawlist-forward-window ()
(interactive)
  (other-window 1)
  (lawlist-minibuffer-conditions))

(defun lawlist-backward-window ()
(interactive)
  (other-window -1)
  (lawlist-minibuffer-conditions))
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE ANSWER (similar concept)**:  `set-face-attribute` is too slow for changing faces during `redisplay`.  The preferred method for adjusting faces in that context is with the function `face-remap-add-relative`; however, that function is a little complicated to use because faces stack up one behind the other and get shadowed.  So, I'll need to revise the following draft alternative answer (in the future) to incorporate `face-remap-add-relative` -- in the meantime, I'm setting the `face-remapping-alist` manually (which admittedly is not the preferred method according to the manual / doc-string).

```lisp
(defvar modeline-selected-window nil)

(let ((default-background (face-background 'default nil 'default)))
 (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-inactive nil :background default-background :box nil))

(defun modeline-record-selected-window ()
  (setq modeline-selected-window (selected-window)))

(defun modeline-update-function ()
  (cond
    ((minibufferp)
      (let ((default-background (face-background 'default nil 'default)))
        (with-selected-window (minibuffer-window)
          (setq-local face-remapping-alist '(
            (default :foreground "blue")
            (minibuffer-prompt :foreground "red"))))
          (setq-default face-remapping-alist `((mode-line ,'mode-line-inactive)))))
    (t
      (with-selected-window (minibuffer-window)
        (when (local-variable-p 'face-remapping-alist)
          (kill-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)))
      (setq-default face-remapping-alist nil))))

(defun modeline-set-format ()
  (setq mode-line-format '(
    (:eval
      (if (eq modeline-selected-window (selected-window))
        (propertize "SELECTED WINDOW" 'face 'font-lock-warning-face)
        (propertize "NOT-SELECTED WINDOW" 'face 'font-lock-keyword-face)))))
  ;; next two lines make the affect immediately apparent
  (setq modeline-selected-window (selected-window))      
  (force-mode-line-update))

(define-minor-mode modeline-mode
"This is a minor-mode for `modeline-mode`."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " ML"
  :keymap nil
  :global t
  :group nil
  (cond
    (modeline-mode
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'modeline-record-selected-window)
      (add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'modeline-update-function)
      (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'modeline-set-format)
      (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
        (message "Globally turned ON `modeline-mode`.")))
    (t
      (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'modeline-record-selected-window)
      (remove-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'modeline-update-function)
      (remove-hook 'text-mode-hook 'modeline-set-format)
      (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
        (message "Globally turned OFF `modeline-mode`.") ))))

(modeline-mode 1) ;; globally turn on minor-mode
```

---

[image: Example]

Comment: Nice idea and inspiring screenshot!

Answer (score 3):

If what you are trying to achieve is to highlight the current buffer/frame, the way I do that is through [Highlight-Current-Line](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/highlight-current-line.el).  It shows you the line where the cursor is, but a side effect of that is that it also shows you which buffer/frame you are in.  You could configure it to highlight the entire buffer, or look into the code to see how they do it.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant by "not really" was that you can't highlight a window, just a buffer, because any modifications to the buffer contents will affect every view of the buffer.  For me, the modeline color + cursor flashing do fine.

Comment: Indeed buffer is better term for that than window. I want to highlight current buffer :)

Answer (score 3):

[***Crosshairs***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CrosshairHighlighting) mode is your best bet, I think.  It not only draws attention to the active window, but it also shows you immediately where the cursor is in an obvious way.  You can easily toggle it on/off (I bind it to `C-+`.)

You can also use `crosshairs-toggle-when-idle` as an alternative. It does not show the crosshairs until a delay has past.  It too is a toggle.

You can of course use crosshairs together with an in-your-face `mode-line` face.

Answer (score 3):

I was using `hiwin-mode` as suggested in this topic but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/yoshida-mediba/hiwin-mode/issues/7) with shell buffers (when inactive, the text becomes invisible).

Therefore, another option which I'm enjoying so far is [auto-dim-other-buffers mode](https://github.com/mina86/auto-dim-other-buffers.el).