# Asking Emacs to highlight more clearly which window (pane) has the focus (cursor)

Tags: emacs

Say I have my Emacs window split into multiple tiles, e.g.:

```
---------------------------
|            |            |
|            |            |
---------------------------
|                         |
|                         |
---------------------------
```

When I switch between tiles (aka windows in Emacs) to edit my files (e.g. using <kbd>C-x o</kbd>), I can see on which tile I am by visually locating the cursor (point) on the screen and checking the difference in shading in the status bar of each tile:

However, locating the cursor on a large screen is not easy AND the difference in shading on the status bar where the cursor is is almost negligible:

This is what a status bar looks like when the corresponding window is selected:

[image: Img1]

This is what it looks like when the corresponding window is **not** selected (notice the green is a bit dimmer)

[image]

The above is with the color theme [zenburn](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/04/zenburn-color-theme.html) on GNU Emacs 23.3.1.

My question is: Is there a way to have Emacs more clearly indicate which window/tile/buffer is the one that has the focus?

Comment: Near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516830/custom-background-for-active-window

Comment: I choose to highlight the mode-line of current window and set the mode-line of other windows the same  background as the theme.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Absolutely!

You can change the modeline to highlight the active bar using the following in your .emacs (change colors and style to suit your preferences of course).

```lisp
(set-face-attribute  'mode-line
                 nil 
                 :foreground "gray80"
                 :background "gray25" 
                 :box '(:line-width 1 :style released-button))
(set-face-attribute  'mode-line-inactive
                 nil 
                 :foreground "gray30"
                 :background MY_BG_COLOR 
                 :box '(:line-width 1 :style released-button))
```

Since it seems you are using the Zenburn color theme, you can also fix it within there.
Just open the file within your color-theme library named zenburn.el (or it might be color-theme-zenburn.el) and search for the following lines:

```lisp
`(mode-line
  ((,class (:foreground ,zenburn-green+1
                       :background ,zenburn-bg-1
                       :box (:line-width -1 :style released-button)))))
`(mode-line-buffer-id ((,class (:foreground ,zenburn-yellow :weight bold))))
`(mode-line-inactive
  ((,class (:foreground ,zenburn-green-1
                       :background ,zenburn-bg-05
                       :box (:line-width -1 :style released-button)))))
```

and change the values of the background and foreground colors as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty good. Is there a way to highlight the current line on the active buffer? It would help a lot to have Emacs do so since it would make it even easier to localize the cursor. I have seen this feature in IDEs and it would be fantastic to have this in Emacs.

Comment: @roseck: `(global-hl-line-mode 1)`

Comment: Note that the `global-hl-line-sticky-flag` variable determines whether it highlights only for the active buffer, or for all buffers, but this should be set as you want it by default. `M-x customize-group RET hl-line RET` for more.

Answer (score 6):

For a quicker solution, you can use the [Smart Mode Line](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line/) plugin for Emacs: a color-coded, fixed width mode line. Works great with the Zenburn theme (I'm using both right now).

It's available in the ELPA, by the way.