# How do I find documentation for this Emacs command?

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446673/asking-emacs-to-highlight-more-clearly-which-window-has-the-focus-cursor) shows how to change a particular Emacs setting with `set-face-attribute`.

Where can I find documentation on **set-face-attribute**?

Normally I find documentation by `C-h a`, followed by a command or fragment of a command.  But doing this for `set-face-attribute` turns up nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard way to get description of function is `C-h f` - press it and type function name (you can use TAB to complete function name).

If you'll press `C-h ?` - you'll get list of all help functions. Another useful keybinding is `C-h v` - to get description of variable.

Comment: Son of a gun, there it is!  I had thought that C-h a (apropos) would cover EVERYTHING.  Obviously I was mistaken.  Thanks.

Comment: `C-h a` is useful when you don't know command/variable name, and wants to find it ;-)