# Split windows in Emacs -- with Tabbar displaying only active buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using a split Emacs frame to move my windows into a more convenient state.
However, there are 2 things that bother me, and I wonder if they can be changed:

1. I'm using tabbar, and all the buffers currently open show on all the window splits. I would like only the buffers available to that current split to appear.
   So if I have `somefile.org` open in the top split and `anotherfile.org` in the bottom, I would like only the corresponding one to appear in each of the tabbar lists (top and bottom).
2. I wonder if there's a possibility to configure the mode line to appear only once in the bottom, and refresh it whenever I move to a different window.
   Something along the line of `tmux`, to those who know - the information is changed based on the windows I'm currently at (although there it's called panes).

**EDIT:**

Regarding point 1:

Say I have 2 open buffers - `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`. The first is shown in a top vertical split, and the other in the bottom one. I would like the top tabbar to only show `file1.txt`, and the bottom to only show `file2.txt`.

Comment: I was confused about item #1 (which is surely possible, but seemed pointless), but I assume you only want it in *conjunction* with item #2 (which would cause you to lose information, some of which you would gain back with #1). I don't think #2 is possible.

Comment: Edited the original post to explain what I need. I'm not asking if it's pointless, but how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to question number 1:

```lisp
(setq tabbar-buffer-groups-function (lambda () (list
  (if (eq (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)) (car (window-list)))
     "my-active-buffer"
     "not-used"))))
```

---

I believe @phils is correct regarding question number 2 -- i.e., it's not possible without modifying the underlying "C" source code that makes Emacs what it is.

---

Here is an alternative approach to question number 2 that makes the background of the mode-line of the inactive window the same color as the background of the buffer.  The original poster can take that code and make the text of the inactive mode-line also the same color as the background of the buffer, which would make the inactive mode-line completely invisible.  However, the visible mode-line would naturally switch locations to whichever window is active.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20936397/2112489

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/modeline-example.png))</sub>