# Do stuff when selecting a window

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've been looking through [the available hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Hooks.html), but none of them seems to be firing when you switch windows.

What I'm trying to do, is activating a minor mode for the selected window:

```lisp
(defvar active-window (frame-selected-window))

(defun active-window-switch (&rest _)
  (when active-window
    (with-selected-window active-window
      (active-window-mode nil)))
  (setq active-window (frame-selected-window))
  (active-window-mode t))

(define-minor-mode active-window-mode
  "Minor mode to distinguish the selected window."
  :global nil :group 'active-window :init-value nil :lighter " Active")

(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook #'active-window-switch)

(provide 'active-window)
```

What hook or function to advice can I use instead of `window-configuration-change-hook` (which only fires when I create or quit windows)?

Comment: Ultimately, I want to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1516830/352796

Comment: Would advising select-window help? (defadvice select-window (after select-window-and-do-stuff activate)
      (do-stuff))

Comment: @AlexVorobiev, thanks, it worked! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your minor mode will be attached to the *buffer*, not the *window*. This shouldn't be a problem, except when the same buffer is displayed multiple times (in different windows or even frames)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select-window` is an operation used internally in many cases, potentially thousands of times in a single command.  You don't really care about the selected window all the time, but only when not running a command.  So the better place to hook yourself is in `post-command-hook`.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. I should probably as well check if the selected window changed so that it doesn't "do stuff" too often. Accepting as a more correct answer.

Comment: Could you provide a working example? Not sure how to use the `post-command-hook` you say, guys :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try advising select-window:

```
(defadvice select-window (after select-window-and-do-stuff activate) 
    (do-stuff))
```

or, if you want to un-do your settings in the window you are leaving first:

```
(defadvice select-window (around select-window-and-do-stuff activate)
    (undo-stuff)
    ad-do-it 
    (do-stuff))
```