# How can I customize the Windows GNU Emacs title bar?

Tags: windows, emacs

On Windows 7, the default title bar is light and semi-translucent. This doesn't coordinate well with the Emacs (GNU v 24) dark theme I've got going, and it seems distracting. Is this kind of Windows GDI stuff accessible from within the lisp environment? Where should I go to look into changing this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the `mode-line` at the bottom of each buffer window?  Something like this example, where it stands out more pronouncely  in the active window:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20936397/2112489

Comment: Thanks, lawlist--not exactly. I'm talking about the margin at the top  that shows the title and minimize/maximize/X buttons.

Comment: You can get rid of the menu-bar in Windows with `(menu-bar-mode -1)`, but I'm not sure how to change its color.  I think the bar above with minimize / maximize is a Windows thing, which is not controlled by Emacs.

Comment: @lawlist, I think Brandon is asking about the decorations around the Emacs frame, not the mode-line, toolbar and menubar inside it. I don't think you can modify these from within Emacs. On Linux, you have to do it from your window manager (Fluxbox, Gnome etc.). I don't know if Windows allows you to customize these features, or if so, how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

See:

> ```
> GNU Emacs Faq :: 5.6 How can I modify the titlebar to contain the current file name?
> https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq.html#Displaying-the-current-file-name-in-the-titlebar
> ```

In particular, the following worked for me just now, for a constant string foo:

```
    (setq frame-title-format "foo")
```

This was under: GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.10) of 2012-09-08 on trouble, modified by Debian, in turn under: Xfce 4.8, in turn under: Debian Linux 7.4.

Answer (score 0):

Window decorations for the Emacs frames are not accessible from Lisp, as they are provided by Windows itself, not by Emacs.  Windows allows you to customize the look of these globally, but it isn't really on topic for this site.

One thing you can do from lisp, at least in the current development version, is make Emacs fullscreen to get rid of the window decorations completely.  By default `toggle-frame-fullscreen` is bound to `F11` in the development Emacs, but earlier versions did not have a keybinding (or the toggle- command, only frame parameters I think, which may not have had full support on Windows)